# HTML element tofront toback

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone think of a better/cleaner/faster approach to arranging DOM elements (please only vanilla javascript):

```js
var frontBackList = [];

function frontBackProc(dir, elem, baseZ) {
  baseZ = baseZ || 100;
  var id = elem.id;
  if (!id) {
    id = elem.id = "rand" + (new Date().getTime());
  }

  if (!~frontBackList.indexOf(id)) {
    frontBackList.push(id);
  }

  var see = 0; // dev
  var loZ = 100000; // max Z is something like 64,000
  var hiZ = -100000;
  for (var i = frontBackList.length; i--;) {
    var el = document.getElementById(frontBackList[i]);

    if (!el) {
      frontBackList.slice(i, 1); // remove missing
    } else {
      var z = Number(el.style.zIndex) || 0;

      if (z <= loZ) {
        loZ = z;
      }
      if (z > hiZ) {
        hiZ = z;
      }
      // dev
      el.style.left = 20 * see + "px";
      el.style.top = 20 * see + "px";
      see++;
    }

  }

  if (dir > 0) {
    elem.style.zIndex = hiZ + 1;
  } else {
    elem.style.zIndex = loZ - 1;
  }


  console.log("bob", elem.style.zIndex);

}

function toFront(elem, baseZ) {
  frontBackProc(1, elem, baseZ);
}

function toBack(elem, baseZ) {
  frontBackProc(-1, elem, baseZ);
}
toFront(document.getElementById("red"));
toFront(document.getElementById("green"));
toFront(document.getElementById("blue"));
toFront(document.getElementById("yellow"));
toFront(document.getElementById("cyan"));

toBack(document.getElementById("blue"));
toFront(document.getElementById("red"));
toFront(document.getElementById("yellow"));
toBack(document.getElementById("red"));
```

```css
.box {
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="red" class="box red">red</div>
<div id="green" class="box green">green</div>
<div id="blue" class="box blue">blue</div>
<div id="yellow" class="box yellow">yellow</div>
<div id="cyan" class="box cyan">cyan</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a ton of unnecessary stuff if the only purpose was just to arrange boxes in a certain pattern. I assume your objective is:

1. Lineup the boxes diagonally
2. Arrange the boxes in an over and under pattern
3. Place them in reverse order

Normally SO main concern is broken code which your's is not, but there is [a site that members analyze working code and help improve it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as I think I have just done, but it was fun, thanks.

---

**Details are commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
/* 
|queryselectorAll()
|| Collect all .box into a NodeList
|Array.from()
|| Convert NodeList into an array
|reverse()
|| Reverse the order of array
*/
var boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box')).reverse();

/* 
|map() will run a function on each element of array
|| if the current index is an even number...
|| give it a z-index of 1
|| otherwise give it a z-index of 2
|| Add a diagonal distance to each element which is
|| incremented by index
*/
boxes.map(function(box, idx, boxes) {
  if ((idx % 2) === 0) {
    box.style.zIndex = 1;
  } else {
    box.style.zIndex = 2;
  }
  box.style.left = 20 * idx + 'px';
  box.style.top = 20 * idx + 'px';
});
```

```css
.box {
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.lime {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">red</div>
<div class="box green">green</div>
<div class="box blue">blue</div>
<div class="box yellow">yellow</div>
<div class="box cyan">cyan</div>
<div class='box lime'>Lime</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the code review site... that's more what I needed. The map is a good idea, and nice tidy code. The method is intended to be generic, and the color and diagonals are just for testing and inspection. Thanks. Oh, and I suppose this may help someone out in the future?

Comment: It helped me in a way because I rarely get to mess around with layout patterns at work, so thank you and you are welcome, sir, happy coding.